# ASP.NET MVC5, Entity Framework How to Insert Data into Multiple Tables in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my `ASP.NET MVC5` with `Entity Framework` project, I have two tables `Account`, `AccountDetail` (`AccountDetail` references to `Account`) with two corresponding models `AccountModel` and `AccountDetailModel`.

In a view(ex: `RegistrationView`), how could I save inputed data in the view into two tables above. Because when creating the `RegistrationView` by right click on the controller, I am able to choose only one model for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can link `AccountModel` and `AccountDetailModel`, and then use `AccountModel`:

```
public AccountModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<AccountDetailModel> Details { get; set; }
}

public AccountDetailModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@model AccountModel
. . .
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Name)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Details[i].Id)
    @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Details[i].Description)
}
```

In the action some code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionView Insert(AccountModel model)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
        var account = new Account();
        account.Id = model.Id;
        account.Name = model.Name;
        account.Details = new List<AccountDetail>();

        dbContext.AddObject(account);

        foreach (var modelDetail in model.Details)
        {
            var accountDetail = new AccountDetail();
            accountDetail.Id = modelDetail.Id;
            accountDetail.Description = modelDetail.Description;
            account.Details.Add(accountDetail);

            dbContext.AddObject(accountDetail);
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you want to update the record, you'll need some code to check, if the related detail record should be inserted or updated.

Comment: Thank you too much for your nice answer. I will try this solution.

Comment: This is the right answer: `AccountModel` is the aggregate here, and really _the_ model in this MVC; `AccountDetailModel` is just a convenient decomposition of `AccountModel`. You should [**accept this as the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but If you want to have both your models in the same view then just create a class like

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public AcountModel AcountModel { get; set; }
    public AcountDetailModel AcountDetailModel { get; set; }
}
```

and use this class for the viewmodel

Comment: I used to do as you, in my controller I create a class:  `public class Account_AccountDetails_Model
        {
            public Account account { get; set; }
            public AccountDetails accountDetails{get; set;}
        } `. And  declare model in the view: `@model SBWebsite.Controllers.AccountController.Account_AccountDetails_Model` but when invoking `@model.` I see a message `The name model does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: Really sorry for the format. I don't know how to make my question esier to see.